# Visual Studio Code install location

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Studio Code a few days ago, and now I can't find the executable on my machine. Where is it?

I have checked Programs and Features. I have also checked my PATH. For some reason it isn't in either.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

**Update 10.11.2018**

If you do a complete re-install, including uninstalling prior versions of code installed on your machine the new version will be installed at

```
C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
```

---

**Update 06.07.2018**

Since Version 1.25 VS Code supports portable mode.
Instructions on how to use this are documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable).

You will need the ZIP file download version - not the installer.
After unzipping the contents of the archive, create a data folder inside the folder, where code.exe is located. All settings will now be saved there and can be brought along with you.

```
|- VSCode-win32-x64-1.25.0-insider
|   |- Code.exe (or code executable)
|   |- data
|   |- ...
```

On macOS, the folder must be named `code-portable-data` and has to be a sibling of the app itself. Not inside the app.

```
|- Visual Studio Code.app
|- code-portable-data
```

The reasoning behind this can be read here: [What is VSCode User Setup for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928174/what-is-vscode-user-setup-for-windows?answertab=votes#tab-top)

---

**Update**

If you are using the x64 version, the path is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe
```

---

**Original answer**

At this point and time (`Version 1.19.2`) Vs code no longer resides in your AppData folder, but under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe
```

Comment: Update: if you use the User Setup version, it will be installed in AppData\Local\Programs by default - see Trollsyn's answer.

Comment: @AJRichardson Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I just installed mine and lost it similar to this question. Mine is installed just like the update, but has a folder named [underscore] containing the executable.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\_\Code.exe

Comment: Why it is installed in user folder instead of the default program files?

Comment: @Pedro77 Two reasons: 1) to allow users without Administrative rights on their machine to install and run the software, and 2) to allow the software to auto-update without needing an elevated prompt or elevated scheduled task (which may introduce a security vulnerability), the problem with this approach is that VSC's executable files now can be edited by non-elevated malicious software.

Comment: Make sure you use the "System Installer" and "Install for All Users" using a system administrator privileged account. Then enable VSCode to "Run As Administrator" by default.  Without the System Installer, you will waste days of your life waiting for Corporate IT to install or update your tools.

Answer (score 28):

There are two types of installer available for VSCode.
Go to [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) to find type of installer you want.

If you are using/going for **User Installer**, the version will be installed at:

```
C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
```

If you are using/going for **64bit System installer**, the version will be installed at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\
```

If you are using/going for **32bit System installer**, the version will be installed at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\
```

Answer (score 20):

I used the new [VSCode User Setup installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928174/what-is-vscode-user-setup-for-windows) on Windows 10, and found the executable here:

```
C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\
```

Comment: Don't do this.  Make sure you use the "System Installer" and "Install for All Users" using a system administrator privileged account. Then enable VSCode to "Run As Administrator" by default.

Answer (score 13):

Okay. [I found it in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup).

```
C:\Users\my.user\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.1.0
```

Comment: I just updated to v0.8.0 and the installation location is now `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code`.

Comment: I'm running version 1.7.1 and it's in the same folder you mentioned.  Which sucks because I would have thought Code would have been a 64 bit program.  Come on Microsoft...it's almost 2017.  Can we have 64 bit now?  lol

Comment: 1.14 => C\Users\my.user\.vscode, C\Users\my.user\AppData\Roaming\Code

Answer (score 5):

The way I find most intuitive and easy to remember is:

1. Search for Visual Studio Code in the Windows 10 search bar -> right-click -> Open File Location

   For me this goes directly to:

   **C:\Users\{YOUR_NAME}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio Code**
2. Right-click on the shortcut -> Properties -> Start in:

   **"C:\Users\{YOUR_NAME}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code"**

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer username-agnostic path strings:

> - folder: `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\`
> - executable: `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code`

If you also want to use those path strings inside C#/C++ code:

> - folder: `"\"%HOMEPATH%\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\\""`
> - executable: `"\"%HOMEPATH%\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin\\code\""`

Answer (score 4):

The difference is:
**System Installer** will install VSC in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\`
**User Installer** will install VSC in `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\`

Search for the files with respect the version installed.

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason none of the other answers work, try this:

1. Go into your vscode settings
2. Find any setting that has 'Edit in settings.json' (for example - Color Customizations)
3. Press ctrl+shift+s
4. Go one folder up
5. Copy + paste the file location (on the top for windows) into into another file explorer
6. Profit

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 with VSC ver 1.73.1 my path is C:\Users{YOUR_USER_HERE}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

I went to system --> environment variables-->path-->edit variables--->new--->pasted C:\Users{YOUR_USER_HERE}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code in there.

typing code on powershell, gitbash works now

Answer (score 1):

Someone I was working with "lost" the shortcut for VSCode.  I started VSCode just by typing "code" from the command line.  Then we recreated the Windows shortcut for the Start Menu.

My advice is to always use the "System Installer" and "Install for All Users" using a system administrator privileged account. Then enable VSCode to "Run As Administrator" by default.  You will have the most flexibility, won't get the VSCode disappointing error "failed build, insufficient privilege to write to folder XYZ" after waiting many minutes for a big virtual environment or build job.

Answer (score 0):

By default your program would be installed here (if you used the System Installer)...

C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\

If you have chosen different directory while installing it you can get it by:

1. Go to the icon location
2. Right click open properties
3. Check target

Answer (score 0):

I found it at

```
C:\Users\%username%\source\repos\Notes\%VSCode-folder%\bin\Debug\
```

Where `%username%` is the user and `%VSCode-folder%` is the VSCode project