# What is VSCode User Setup for Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On a Windows workstation after a recent update of VSCode I'm prompted (recommended) to install a "User Setup Distribution of VSCode for Windows"

The link for more info leads to:

> Download User Setup
>
> If you are a current user of the system-wide Windows setup, you will be prompted to switch to the user setup, which we recommend using from now on. Don't worry, all your settings and extensions will be kept during the transition.

I don't see anything that explains what changes this distribution makes or how it's different from a distribution for other platforms, like X11/linux.

Code is a great editor, so I use it on various platforms depending where I am.  Where is the explanation of what is included in this updated "Distribution"?

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_user-setup-for-windows

---

Famous Question Badge Celebration! : love to VSCodium https://vscodium.com/ ... and highly recommend to anyone interested in  this Q.

Comment: The question is very confusing because **no context** is provided. When are you prompted? What program prompts you? What are you trying to do?

Comment: "system-wide", what you have now, means that every user that logs in to the machine can use VSCode.  This is not a very common requirement, most programmers have a machine that only they use and always log in with the same username+password.  But it is a bit more hassle to get it updated, you get the UAC elevation prompt to update.  What they like now, the user-specific setup, can avoid this.  It stores VSCode stuff in a user-specific directory that can be written to without UAC elevation.  So if you are the only user of the machine, or have lots of disk space, then you like the recommendation

Answer (score 53, accepted):

VSCode User Setup is a new installer, with a new install strategy, which installs the whole executable for VSCode and its dependencies in directories which don't require system-level / administrator permissions to modify. This allows a few things:

- Users who don't have admin privileges to their workstation can still install and use VS Code
- VS Code can perform its updates with fewer prompts (basically without the system-level privilege escalation prompts)

One tip: If you already had VSCode installed as a system-wide installation and you switch to the new installer as prompted/recommended, the User Setup installer will suggest that you uninstall the system-wide install first. I was a little nervous that I might lose my extensions doing this, but I went ahead and tried it and am happy to report that my extensions, recent projects, and other data regarding my VSCode use remained intact between uninstalling the "old" version and then proceeding with install of the new User Setup version.

Comment: Very clear answer, but it might be worth noting (if you do have knowledge of it, of course) whether or not the "user setup" version will eventually replace the system-wide setup in the future, or they will keep going with both setup versions in parallel.

Comment: Dusty, were you using the [Settings Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) extension or was the recovery of your previous environment built in to VSCode?

Comment: @pilau - No, I don't have that extension. It seems VSCode carried over my settings from the system-wide install to the new User Setup install without any external help.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. I was asking due to [this issue](https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync/issues/709)

Comment: For me installing the user version didn't uninstall the system version, and I couldn't get anything to work properly. I had to completely uninstall both versions and start again, now it seems OK

Comment: My advice is to always use the "System Installer" and "Install for All Users" using a system administrator privileged account. Then enable VSCode to "Run As Administrator" by default. You will have the most flexibility, won't get the VSCode disappointing error "failed build, insufficient privilege to write to folder XYZ" after waiting many minutes for a big virtual environment or build job.  You also won't have to wait for Corporate IT to update your installation or extensions.

Answer (score 7):

(I'm a first time responder after many years.)
Note there is another useful discussion on this subject at: ([What is the migration procedure for moving from Windows system-wide Visual Studio Code to user setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831578/what-is-the-migration-procedure-for-moving-from-windows-system-wide-visual-studi)).  I too got worried when I got unexpected messages from the install informing me that the version was already installed and asking me if I wanted to continue? I clicked NO, why continue if it is already installed. However, in the process I became aware of the distinction between 'distribution' and 'version'. It turns out that the install works *pretty much* flawlessly no matter how you go about it. You can delete the system-wide distribution or not. If you do delete, you can delete before the new install, (which I did). You can also delete after the new install. (I didn't read too closely but there might be an extra step if you want to use both distributions.) In hindsight, since all approaches work *nearly* flawlessly, a minimal amount of instruction is all that was required. But in foresight, a little extra information on what to expect would have expedited the process for several people, including me. P.S. I found the answers in this thread useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the page you link to:

> This setup does not require Administrator privileges to install. It also provides a smoother background update experience.

Comment: literally from the anchor within the page he linked to

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to always use the "System Installer" and "Install for All Users" using a system administrator privileged account. Then enable VSCode to "Run As Administrator" by default. You will have the most flexibility, won't get the VSCode disappointing error "failed build, insufficient privilege to write to folder XYZ" after waiting many minutes for a big virtual environment or build job. You also won't have to wait for Corporate IT to update your installation or extensions.  The "User Installer" leaves you at the mercy of Corporate IT for building your own system-level tools and utilities.